# How do I view a PostgreSQL database on heroku with a GUI?

Tags: postgresql, user-interface, heroku

I have a rails app on heroku that is using a Postgre database. My database has > 40 tables and > 10,000 rows. I would like to delete a lot of data, but it would be much easier if I was able to view and interact with it in a GUI table. I can access my data in rails console, but it's taking too long.

Comment: Well just choose a GUI like Squirrel or PGadmin etc and go from there, see if you can connect and let us know if you have problems

Answer (score 37):

[pgweb](http://sosedoff.github.io/pgweb/) is a great cross-platform GUI, and it's  easy to connect to your Heroku Postgres when launching from the command line.

I installed via Homebrew on a Mac (`brew install pgweb`), but instructions for other platforms are listed on the site. Here's how I launch pgweb connected to a Heroku Postgres DB:

`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL | xargs pgweb --url`

And if you want to connect to your localhost:

`pgweb --host localhost`

Comment: Wow, that was so much easier than I thought it was going to be. Looks promising already!

Comment: I am on Windows 10 and am having trouble installing pgweb. Does anyone have a link to a good guide for this.

Comment: Yeah, available on the readme as a one liner: `pgweb_windows_amd64.exe --url postgres://.....` Don't add `?ssl=1` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late here, but this may help someone else who stumbles across this thread...

If you go to your Heroku app's dashboard (through the website) > settings > "Reveal Config Vars" > DATABASE_URL, and paste that URL into the browser.

I use TablePlus for database management, when I paste the link into the browser it asks if it can open TablePlus and then I can edit my production database in real time just like I would in development.

I'm not sure what pasting the URL into the browser will do if you don't have TablePlus. I assume it will request to open any other SQL management app you might have.

Comment: I had Postico installed locally and did the same thing. A dialog box popped up and asked for confirmation. Everything else just worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As slumdog wrote in the comment to your question, you can use pgAdmin, which comes with your local Postgres installation.

This article explains how to connect your remote heroku db with pgAdmin, using heroku credentials: https://medium.com/@vapurrmaid/getting-started-with-heroku-postgres-and-pgadmin-run-on-part-2-90d9499ed8fb

From the article:

"pgAdmin is a GUI for postgresql databases that can be used to access and modify databases that not only exist locally, but also remotely. For a fresh install of pgAdmin, the dashboard likely contains only one server. This is your local server...
We have to configure a new remote server with its credentials.

- right click server(s) > create > server …

  Fill out the following:
- Name: This is solely for you. Name it whatever you want, I chose ‘Heroku-Run — On’
- Under the connection tab: hostname/address. If you go back to your datastores ‘reveal credentials’, this is the host credential. It should look like **-**-**...amazonaws.com
- Keep the port at 5432, unless your credentials list otherwise
- Maintenance database — this is the database field in the credentials
- Username — this is the user field in the credentials
- Password — the password field in the credentials. I highly advise checking save password so that you don’t have to copypasta this every time you want to connect.
- In the SSL tab, mark SSL mode as require

At this point, if we were to hit **‘save’ (please don’t)**, something very strange would happen. You’d see hundreds if not thousands of databases appear in pgAdmin. This has to do with how Heroku configures their servers. You’ll still only have access to your specific database, not those of others. In order to avoid parsing so many databases, we have to white list only those databases we care about.

- go to the Advanced tab and under db restriction copy the database name (it’s the same value as the Maintenance database field filled earlier)."

Article contains other usefull guidelines and screenshots.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide context for links. 
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use Heroku's hosted DB viewer on the `Overview` pane of your dashboard:

[image: Heroku DB launcher]

Create and click the Dataclip:

[image: Heroku Datastore]

Dataclip GUI is fairly easy to use, we can type and customize SQL queries at the top etc.

[image: PostgreSQL Dataclip Viewer]

Answer (score 0):

Try GUI of **DBWeaver**.
https://dbeaver.io/
Download it, after that you can connect your **heroku postgres** using **Database Credentials data**.